# Will buying a non sleep dyno on Heroku allow me to upload files without loosing them?

Tags: node.js, file, heroku, upload, dyno

If I used a paid (non-sleep) dyno, can I push code and ignore the uploads directory in the .gitignore file, so my uploaded files are not lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
A dyno is a container (much like docker) that is built when you deploy your app. It can be started one or many times, and won't share anything.
When you restart/redeploy the app, the filesystem will always be lost and reset to what it was when you deployed the app.

You need to store your uploaded files on a dedicated storage platform such as Amazon S3.
See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node